# EF Core 3.1 / MySQL - OrderByDescending is ignored after Distinct()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I run this query

```
       var query = await _db.Production
                .OrderByDescending(q => q.Id)
                .Where(q => q.Industry > 0)
                .Select(m => m.FromCompany).Distinct().Take(10).ToListAsync()
```

And get the following

> ```
>   Executed DbCommand (64ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
>   SELECT DISTINCT `j`.`from_company`
>   FROM `production` AS `j`
>   WHERE (`j`.`Industry` > 0)
>   LIMIT @__p_0
> ```

However, I expected to see

> ORDER BY `production`.`id` DESC

Which I did at the begging

> .OrderByDescending(q => q.Id)

How can I order after distinct?

---

Update.

> If I put order after distinct, I will not be able to sort by ID:
> Error CS1061  'int' does not contain a definition for 'Id' and no
> accessible extension method 'Id' accepting a first argument of type
> 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)

Comment: The OrderBy has to come _after_ the Distinct. To get the ID at that location, use an anonymous object pass-through - or use GroupBy. It is not logical/guaranteed (hence why it is dropped) to order by a column not carried through the set.

Comment: @user28647400 I've reported this issue will be warned in future releases https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23267

Comment: Nice. A warning would likely save lots of headaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PS I've reported this "issue"

Now it is "fixed" and people will get warnings in .net 6

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/pull/24160